# Karate-Chrome docker container in azure dev ops failing to connect

Tags: docker, azure-devops, connection, karate

I have seen many similar issues to this but none seem to resolve or describe my exact issue.

I have configured an azure devops pipeline to use a container like below:

```
    container:
      image: ptrthomas/karate-chrome
      options: --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN
```

I have uploaded the contents of the example from the jobserver demo to a repository and then run the following:

```
 steps:
    - script: mvn clean test -DargLine='-Dkarate.env=docker' -Dtest=WebRunner
```

It is my understanding (and I can see from the logs) that the files are loaded **into** the container and the script command is being executed **inside** the container. So that script command is the equivalent of `docker exec -it -w /src karate mvn clean test -DargLine='-Dkarate.env=docker' -Dtest=WebRunner` just without having to exec into the container.

When I run the example locally it executes the tests with no issues but in azure dev ops it fails at the point the tests actually start running, throwing this error:

> 14:16:37.388 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
> localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
> (Connection refused), http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url:
> http://localhost:9222/json 14:16:39.388 [main] DEBUG
> com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - attempt #4 waiting for http to be
> ready at: http://localhost:9222/json 14:16:39.391 [main] DEBUG
> com.intuit.karate - request: 5 > GET http://localhost:9222/json 5 >
> Host: localhost:9222 5 > Connection: Keep-Alive 5 > User-Agent:
> Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_275) 5 > Accept-Encoding:
> gzip,deflate

Looking at other issues there have been suggestions to specify the driver in the feature files with this line:

```
  * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', executable: 'chrome' }
```

but a) that hasn't worked for me and b) shouldn't the karate-chrome docker image render this configuration unnecessary as it should be no different than the container I run locally?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: really hard for me to give you any pointers, I'll ask around :|

Comment: One small thing to add, you don't need `clean` in the Maven command.  You are spinning up a fresh container on every run, nothing to clean.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can think of is that the Azure config does not call the `ENTRYPOINT` of the image.

Maybe you should try to create a container from scratch (that does extensive logging) and see what happens. Use the Karate one as a reference.

EDIT: most likely a change in Selenium / Webdriver, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2358